# Prove that $ i) \sum_{k}^{n}{f(k)} = nf(n) - \int_{1}^{n} f'(x)dx $

Tags: real-analysis

Suppose f' is continuous. Prove that
 $$ i) \sum_{k}^{n}{f(k)} = nf(n) - \int_{1}^{n} f'(x)[x]dx $$
$$ ii) \sum_{k=1}^{2n}(-1)^kf(k) = \int_1^{2n} f'(x)([x] - 2[\frac{x}{2}]dx $$

I don't know how to do this excercise, or what piece of theory should I study, in order to be able to solve this and have an idea of what i should do.
Maybe someone can tell me how to start or what particular theme should I study, or what other problem is similar to this one?

Comment: It seems to me that (i) is not true? There is certainly a counterexample: $f(x)=\sin(\pi x/2)$. If you choose $n=3$, then $\sum_{k=1}^3\sin(\pi k/2)=0$, but $$3\sin(3\pi/2)-\int_1^3\frac{\pi}{2}\cos(\pi x/2)dx=3\sin(3\pi/2)-\sin(3\pi /2)+\sin(\pi/2)=-3$$

Comment: It is not -3, but -1. Anyway it looks incorrect... I now know that the theme is riemman-stieltdjes integration

Comment: oh, but i missed something...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(i). Note that
$$\begin{aligned}\int_1^n f'(x)[x]dx&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_k^{k+1}f'(x)[x]dx=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k\int_k^{k+1}f'(x)dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}k[f(k+1)-f(k)]\\
&=(n-1)f(n)-f(1)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}[k-(k+1)]f(k+1)\\
&=(n-1)f(n)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}f(k)
\end{aligned}$$

(ii)For each $k\in\{1,\dots,n-1\}$ we have
$$\begin{aligned}\int_{2k}^{2(k+1)}2\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]f'(x)dx&=\int_{2k}^{2(k+1)}2kf(x)dx=2k(f(2(k+1))-f(2k))
\end{aligned}$$
and note that $\int_{1}^{2}2\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]f'(x)dx=0$ as $\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]=0$ for $x\in[1,2]$.
Hence
$$\begin{aligned}\int_1^{2n}2\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]f(x)dx&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}\int_{2k}^{2(k+1)}2\left[\frac{x}{2}\right]f'(x)dx\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2k(f(2(k+1))-f(2k))\\
&=2(n-1)f(2n)-2f(2)+\sum_{k=1}^{n-2}(2k-2(k+1))f(2(k+1))\\
&=2(n-1)f(2n)-\sum_{k=1}^{n-1}2f(2k)
\end{aligned}$$
Combining this with the analysis of (i). The result follows.